# Using Sharepoint Office 365 to display data

Tags: sharepoint, office365

I am completely new Office 365 (and SharePoint) but have been asked to create a site that will display a range of data in the form of graphs and tables etc The data will change daily and therefore it must be possible for members of the team to enter new raw data, for the results to then be displayed through Office 365.

I realise this might sound a little vague but my initial thoughts are that SharePoint is what I should use to display the data and to have a SQL backend database that stores the data for SharePoint to connect to. Having done some reading on the topic and I am still a little unsure if this is common practice or even possible.

Any inital pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with Power BI. The data sources can by almost anything, SQL, spreadsheets, online sources, you name it. Create queries to get the data, model it (if required) and build reports and dashboards that display in a browser (or on a phone).

Comment: Thanks - having a look at this now. Do I assume that Power BI is a seperate application altogether or does it integrate with Office 365?

Comment: It integrates with Office 365, it's free for personal use and the Pro version is included in the E5 plan.